# dynamic checkbox value access in another file in PHP

Tags: php, html

i am facing problem i am developing school system in php.
i want use checkbox dynamic for attendance but checkbox value i cant use in another file please help me

first file attendacne.php

```
    <form name="abc" method="post" action="attendance-con.php">
    <p>Date: 
    <input name="dat" type="text" class="tcal"/>
    <input name="Save" type="submit"  style="float:right 20ox;" value="Save Attendace" />
    <input name="class_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['class_id']; ?> " />
    <?php

    $a=0;
    $qry=("SELECT DISTINCT
    s.rollnum as rollnum,
    s.std_name as name 
    FROM  student s WHERE s.std_class=".$_REQUEST['class_id']."");
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
    <table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" style="text-align:left;" id="stname">
    <?php
    if($a==0)
    { ?>     
    <tr>
    <th width="117" height="39" bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Student RollNo</th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Student Name</th>
    <th width="100" bgcolor="#ECFAFF">Present</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    }?>
    <?php
    if($a==1)
    { ?>
    <tr>
    <th width="117" height="-5" bgcolor="#FFE1CC"></th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFE1CC"></th>
    <th width="100" bgcolor="#ECFAFF"></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php $a=1; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="rollnum[]" value="<?php echo $row['rollnum'];?>"/><tr>
<td> 
    <?php echo $row['rollnum'];?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $row['name'];?>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="stid[]" value="1">
</td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </table>
    </form>
```

second file attendance-con.php

```
    <?php
include_once("include/config.php");
    $i=0;
    $Dat=$_POST['dat'];
    $cid=$_POST['class_id'];

    $sid=$_POST['stid'];

    foreach($_POST['rollnum'] as $x)
    {
    if($sid[$i]=='1')
{
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO attendance (sid,cid,Date,status)
    values('$x','$cid','$Dat','1')");
}
    if($sid[$i]!='1')
{
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO attendance (sid,cid,Date,status)
    values('$x','$cid','$Dat','0')");
}
    $i=$i+1;      
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You must learn to differ between client and server side. There is no such thing as a checkbox value on server side, since such thing is only defined in cientside interpretation of the html markup DOM. For server side php this is all just text. Therefore you have to consider how to get the value on the _client_ side and where you want to use that value. If that is on some server side script (php), then you have to transfer and store the value somehow (ajax).

Comment: mean i do this in html not in php???

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stid" value="1">
```

not

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stid[]" value="1">
```

Comment: but i am using dynamic checkbox mean run time increase number of chechboxes thatis why i use [] brackets... what you say real problem is?